# How to find and delete row that is not in A but in B?

Tags: r

I have a stock market chart for spot market and forwards market for price. Now I want to compare the price of them at a same day. But I found the forwards market has 1826 days and spot market has 1822 days observations. I do not know what are the days of the 4 days that are missing in spot market. Can you guys give me syntax on how to find those 4 more observations in forwards market that are missing in spot market? I can't just delete random 4 observations. The days should be matching.

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Have a great day!

Comment: [please give a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). how are your data stored? as vectors? a `data.frame`?

Comment: It is data.frame. there is one data frame with forwards price and date from 2015/12/31 to 2011/1/1. The same goes with spot price. But forwards has 1826 observations which is 4 more than spot. I do not know where the 4 observations come from..

Comment: join the two data frames using the date. there may be more than 4 that don't match.

Comment: That's where I am stuck. I tried to put them together, but because the number of observations are different, I cant put them together.. I tried those two advice down there, and it did not really work. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry I don't have a computer available. just search for how to join two data.frames and update your question to reflect where you're still stuck after trying to replicate any of several similar. questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer `data.table`. See [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for an intro to the syntax.

## Setup

```
library(data.table)
# use setDT(forwards) on your own object to convert an existing data.frame
set.seed(20384)
all_dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2011-01-01'), as.Date('2015-12-31'), by = 'day')
TT = length(all_dates)
forward = data.table(
  date = all_dates,
  price_forward = rnorm(TT)
)
forward
#             date price_forward
#    1: 2011-01-01    -0.0969564
#    2: 2011-01-02    -0.1079899
#    3: 2011-01-03     1.9454087
#    4: 2011-01-04     0.5079781
#    5: 2011-01-05     0.2201317
#   ---                         
# 1822: 2015-12-27    -0.3674510
# 1823: 2015-12-28    -1.5389197
# 1824: 2015-12-29    -0.8461961
# 1825: 2015-12-30    -0.7018287
# 1826: 2015-12-31    -0.5643040
spot = data.table(
  # simulate removing 4 of the dates at random
  date = sample(all_dates, TT - 4L),
  price_spot = rnorm(TT - 4),
  # setting key is not necessary, but it will sort the data
  key = 'date'
)
spot
#             date  price_spot
#    1: 2011-01-01  0.33803547
#    2: 2011-01-02 -1.21756020
#    3: 2011-01-03  0.13199130
#    4: 2011-01-04 -0.64201342
#    5: 2011-01-05 -0.08061704
#   ---                       
# 1818: 2015-12-27  1.83826974
# 1819: 2015-12-28  0.22838840
# 1820: 2015-12-29 -0.93258147
# 1821: 2015-12-30 -1.20209606
# 1822: 2015-12-31 -1.80698627
```

## Investigation

Identifying the missing dates is easy. e.g.

```
setdiff(forward$date, spot$date)
# [1] 15212 15598 16188 16752
# strangely, setdiff strips the Date of its human-readable label
#   and converted the dates to integers (read ?Date for more);
#   we can recover the useful version with (note that this version
#   is inefficient since we convert to character every Date object,
#   when we only care about the character version of a few -- we 
#   would do better to convert the result of setdiff):
setdiff(paste(forward$date), paste(spot$date))
# [1] "2011-08-26" "2012-09-15" "2014-04-28" "2015-11-13"
```

But that's probably not all you'd like to do; joining the tables may be more useful:

```
prices = merge(forward, spot, all.x = TRUE, by = 'date')
# once merged, we can use is.na to identify the missing dates:
prices[is.na(price_spot)]
#          date price_forward price_spot
# 1: 2011-08-26   0.008345504         NA
# 2: 2012-09-15  -0.966410632         NA
# 3: 2014-04-28  -1.600574836         NA
# 4: 2015-11-13   1.549928470         NA
```

Comment: Dear Chirico, I have done setdiff on my dataset, but it does show weird stuff. It is showing like [1] 1451520000 1451433600 1451347200 1451260800 1451174400 1451088000 1451001600 1450915200 1450828800 1450742400 1450656000 1450569600 1450483200 1450396800
  [15] 1450310400 1450224000 1450137600 1450051200 1449964800 1449878400 1449792000 1449705600 1449619200 1449532800 1449446400 1449360000 1449273600 1449187200
and so on.. I do not know what the problem is. If possible, I can send you my data.. How can I do that? Thank you for help very much!

Comment: Please read my answer more carefully. The only difference is your data appears to be stored as `POSIXct` instead of `Date`

Answer (score 1):

consider `setdiff`: something like

```
setdiff(forward, spot)
```

where forward and spot are the respective days should give you the days that differ between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will delete the non matching rows:

```
forwards <- forwards[ forwards$date %in% spot$date, ]
```